# Form model not validating before POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make a registration page in my web application. However, the validation on my form is not working. For example I have my password minimum length be 4 charterers but if I enter a blank password it still makes the POST request. How do I tell the form that the model is not valid and that they should change their password,email, etc?

**AccountController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model){
    if (ModelState.IsValid){
        // Insert into database
    }
    // There was an error
    return View(model);
}
```

RegisterModel.cs

```
public class RegisterModel
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 4)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Register.cshtml

```
@model RegisterModel
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="UserName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Soultion**
Since The Register page was under Home controller, and the Register logic was in the Account controller i had to define the the view to load the Register.cshtml page.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model){
    if (ModelState.IsValid){
        // Insert into database
    }
    // There was an error
    return View("~/Views/Home/Register.cshtml",model)
}
```

Comment: OP: this is **not** *ASP.NET MVC*, this is *ASP.NET Core*

Comment: @cFrozenDeath , yeah its still ASP.NET MVC, its call ASP.NET MVC 6 or ASP.NET 5

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/02/01/an-update-on-asp-net-core-and-net-core/

Comment: have you included the jquery unobtrusive validation files (probably should be in your `_Layout.cshtml`)?

Comment: Look at the generated markup.  Do you see data-val-* attributes?

Comment: When you submit the form, it should be posted. rite ?What is the behavior you are  expecting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the submit button, it posts the form to the server where your action method has code to check whether the form is valid ( `ModelState.IsValid`). This is server side validation. The form has to be posted to server for this to happen.

If you want to the validation to happen at client side (and not submit the form if the validation fails), you need to make sure that you have the relevant javascript libraries/files loaded to your page.

1. jquery.validate.js
2. jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

You may include those in your layout file or your specific view. If it is the specific view, make sure you include those in the Scrips section.

```
@section Scripts
{
 <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation- unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
}
```

Update the path of the files to match with where you have those files in your  project. You may also use the location to a public cdn.

Comment: Well im ok with it happening server side. For example i have ConfirmPassword element. That checks to see if the password is the same as the confirmed password. In the model i compare the two, so if they don’t equal each other how do i then send that back to the client. Is there a way to check the Model state for which field is invalid ?

Comment: The `return View(model);` line will send the posted model back to the view(with relevant error messages). If you are purticular about seeing which one failed, Take a look at [How to figure out which key of ModelState has error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296069/how-to-figure-out-which-key-of-modelstate-has-error);

Comment: return View(model); just process "Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.".  Could this be a routing issue. My registration page is in my Home controller but the form POST to the Account controller.

Comment: Then you have to explicitly return to that view like `return View("~/Views/Home/Registration",model);`

Comment: return View("~/Views/Home/Registration",model); gives me the same error. Do i have to change it from  "public IActionResult Register()" to "public IActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)" ? Or maybe a different address?

Comment: No. Your get action dont need to be updated. You should find out why it is throwing the errror. Sorry i have no idea why it fails because i can't see your code.

Comment: return View("~/Views/Home/Register"); returns an error as well, so maybe the route is messed up, ill play around with it

Comment: Sorry ! I missed the file extension last time. Try `return View("~/Views/Home/Registration.cshtml",model);`

Comment: Yeah ok so if i change it to             return View("~/Views/Home/Register.cshtml");, the validation works. Since you helped me figure it out. Ill give you the credit.

Comment: Thanks Shyju. I was wondering if i could ask you one more question. Do you know of a way where, i can do a check, say the username already exists, and if it does i can set the model to be invalid? Would i have to make a new property in the model ?

Comment: You can use `ModelState.AddModelError` See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144221/username-availability-and-insert-new-user

Comment: Thanks for all the help i wish i could give you ten more points.