# model not validating before POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have my model and my view. Everything is working fine. The only problem is that its not showing the warning sign as expected. i have added data annotation in the model.

If a field that is required stays empty I get a error. I expect that if something required is messing it will not submit and it will show a warning sign.

This is my model:

```
public partial class RecipeV
{
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description required")]
    [StringLength(5)]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IngredientV Ingredient { get; set; }

    public DirectionV Direction { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@model RecipesBlog.Models.ViewModels.RecipeV

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create Recipe</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredient.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    <p> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Ingredient[@i].Text"><br></p>
                }
                <div class="Ingredient"></div>

                <input class="add_Ingredient" type="text" value="&#43" />

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ingredient.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Direction.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    <p> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Direction[@i].Text"><br></p>
                }
                <div class="Directions"></div>

                <input class="add_Direction" type="text" value="&#43" />

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Direction.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>

        </div>



    <div class="form-group">

    </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
}
```

This is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Recipe recipe, List<Ingredient> ingredient, List<Direction> direction)
```

I added a try catch so now it will not submit if there is error.

```
        try
        {
            recipe.Date = DateTime.Now;
            // Add the new recipe to the recipes table.
            db.Recipes.InsertOnSubmit(recipe);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
           return View();
        }

    int id = recipe.RecipeID;

    foreach (Ingredient i in ingredient)
    {
        if (i.Text != null)
        {
            i.RecipeID = id;
            db.Ingredients.InsertOnSubmit(i);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }               
    }

    foreach (Direction d in direction)
    {
        if (d.Text != null)
        {
            d.RecipeID = id;
            db.Directions.InsertOnSubmit(d);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    //Direct the user to the index page. 
    return RedirectToAction("index", "Recipes", new { id = recipe.RecipeID });
}
```

Comment: What warning are you talking about ? When are you expecting that to show up ?

Comment: the validation warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I did:

I downloaded the js validation files and added it at the end of the view.  As recommended by @Shyju Thank you all for the help.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

This is how it looks:

```
@model RecipesBlog.Models.ViewModels.RecipeV
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create Recipe</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredient.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    <p> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Ingredient[@i].Text"><br></p>
                }
                <div class="Ingredient"></div>

                <input class="add_Ingredient" type="text" value="&#43" />

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ingredient.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Direction.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    <p> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Direction[@i].Text"><br></p>
                }
                <div class="Directions"></div>

                <input class="add_Direction" type="text" value="&#43" />

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Direction.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>

        </div>



    <div class="form-group">

    </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current code inside your Create HttpPost action method tries to save the data and do a redirect which is a new GET call. If you want to see the validation errors in the form you submitted, you should return the same view. Modelstate dictionary will have the validation errors(if any) and when the view is rendered, they will be displayed.

It is a good practice to check `ModelState.IsValid` property to see whether model validation failed before continuing to save the data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Recipe recipe, List<Ingredient> ingredient,
                                                                  List<Direction> direction)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       return View(vm);   // validation failed. Return the same view

    //continue executing your save & redirect code
}
```

Comment: It's not helping.

Comment: What is happening with this code change ? Is your form being submitted without filling all required fields ? What is happening then ?

Comment: @coco your comment isn't helping. We can't look at your screen. You need to read [ask] and explain very explicitly what you expect to happen, what actually happens and what you have tried to resolve the differences between the two.

Comment: I'm not getting the warning .I'm getting a error as before.

Comment: @coco you never mentioned an error before, please read my previous comment.

Comment: If you do not want the form to be submitted, you need to include the relevant jQuery unobutrusive validate plugin files.

Comment: the data annotation validation is not enough in MVC?

Comment: That does only server side validation. If you want that to happen in client side (before the form data reaches the server action method), you need to  use those client side libraries mentioned in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/38513271/40521

Answer (score 1):

Also you should receive the model RecipeV not the domain.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(RecipeV model, List<Ingredient> ingredient, List<Direction> direction)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
           // do something
            //Direct the user to the index page. 
            return RedirectToAction("index", "Recipes", new { id = recipe.RecipeID });
        }
```

Comment: you can receive model and then check ModelState.IsValid and then bind model data with domain then save to db